# Strip parameter values from URL

Tags: parsing, url, sed, parameters

I'd like to strip parameter values from a URL, but leave the parameter names in place:  I.e.,
Change

```
http://abc.def.edu/pager/page.cfm?pai=97878&pager=123
```

into

```
http://abc.def.edu/pager/page.cfm?pai=&pager=
```

I've tried:

```
sed "s/=.*\&/=\&/g"
```

With no success.  Am I getting close? I've seen lots of posts about stripping parameters entirely, but nothing about just stripping the values.  Please redirect me and accept my apologies if this has already been addressed.

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's/=[^\&]+/=/g' <<< 'http://abc.def.edu/pager/page.cfm?pai=97878&pager=123'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
http://abc.def.edu/pager/page.cfm?pai=&pager=
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more heavy-weight than `sed`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<==).+?(?=&|$)//g' <<< "$url"
http://abc.def.edu/pager/page.cfm?pai=&pager=
```